# the metadataObj.stringValue coming from the QR code wont be assigned to a variable on another class

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

So I have to Implement a Login function with QR code, when user scans the qr code through the app the value inside the qr which is in string must be parsed to a variable on another class so that the API can get the data from that variable's id.

1. user scan a qr code which contains a string value: 0E79C6205FD04F8994B13F5255B7FFD2
2. the string from qr must be parsed to another class in variable `var id: String = ""`
3. the API class takes that string thats coming from the qr code into the id var and shows the data.

but the problem is that the string isn't being parsed to that variable id in the other class and I did tons of research and posts but nothing that could help even some seniors on iOS couldnt figure it out! , a mystery or impossible?

The code of the QRCodeViewController:

```
extension QRScannerController: AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {
func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    // Check if the metadataObjects array is not nil and it contains at least one object
    if metadataObjects.count == 0 {
        qrCodeFrameView?.frame = CGRect.zero
        qrmessageLabel.text = "Asnje QR-code nuk eshte Detektuar!"
        return
    }
    
    // Get the metadata object
    let metadataObj = metadataObjects[0] as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject
    
    if supportedCodeTypes.contains(metadataObj.type) {
        // If the found metadata is equal to the QR code metadata then update the status label's text and set the bounds
        let barCodeObject = videoPreviewLayer?.transformedMetadataObject(for: metadataObj)
        qrCodeFrameView?.frame = barCodeObject!.bounds
        
        if metadataObj.stringValue != nil {
            let qrcode = metadataObj.stringValue!
            let destVC = MonitorimiViewController()
            destVC.id = qrcode
            destVC.modalTransitionStyle = .flipHorizontal
            destVC.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
            present(destVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
}
```

If you see clearly the code: `(tabBarController.viewControllers![0] as? MonitorimiViewController)?.id = metadataObj.stringValue!` is trying to assign the stringValue coming from the qr code to the variable id in the MonitorimiViewController class but its just not being parsed?

the MonitorimiViewController code:

```
class MonitorimiViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate{


@IBOutlet weak var monitorimiTableView: UITableView!



@IBOutlet weak var searchField: UISearchBar!    


var listOfVechicle = [Vehicles]()
var listOfVehicles = [Vehicles]()


var id: String!     


let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    monitorimiTableView.delegate = self   // Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value
    monitorimiTableView.dataSource = self
    monitorimiTableView.rowHeight = 225
    
    fetchAndReloadData()
    
    refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Duke u përditësuar")
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refresh), for: .allEvents)
    monitorimiTableView.addSubview(refreshControl) 
}


@objc func refresh(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    fetchAndReloadData()
    monitorimiTableView.reloadData()
    refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}


 func fetchAndReloadData(){
    APICaller.shared.getVehicles(for: id) {[weak self] (result) in
        guard let self = self else { return }
        
        switch result {
        case .success(let vehicle):
            self.listOfVechicle = vehicle
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.monitorimiTableView.reloadData()
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
}


extension MonitorimiViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return listOfVechicle.count
}



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "monitorimiCell", for: indexPath) as? MyCustomCell1 else {return UITableViewCell()}
    let currentVechicle = listOfVechicle[indexPath.row]

    
    cell.veturaOutlet.text = currentVechicle.Plate
    cell.shpejtsiaAktualeOutlet.text = currentVechicle.Speed!
    cell.perditsuarOutlet.text = "\(currentVechicle.LastCommunicationDate!.convertToDisplayForm())"
    cell.pasagjereOutlet.text = "\(currentVechicle.Passengers!) Person/a"
    cell.vozitesiOutlet.text = "\(currentVechicle.Driver!)"

    
    return cell
}

}
```

Also wana add that there is the API class which fetches the string from var id and makes a GET request to the data and show them in the appropriate classes

I have been stuck with this problem since couple of days "4-5 days"
For any clarifications please feel free to comment.

Comment: Is `(tabBarController.viewControllers![0] as? MonitorimiViewController)` nil?

Comment: its not nil, while debugging the. string goes till there then it just not being assigned to the var id on the other class. Its unexplainable this thing

Comment: Where do you see that `id` isn't set? Because you call yourself `refresh(_:)`? Since `viewDidLoad()` might not be called. Could you write a `didSet` for `var id: String`? To be sure it's written? Also, could add `print("self: \(self)")` in `viewDidLoad()`, and `viewDidAppear()` of ``MonitorimiViewController`, just to be sure there is no instance issue?

Comment: i see that its not being set because i printed the id in debugging on viewDidLoad

Comment: And in viewDidAppear? Is really the set of id happening before viewDidLoad? Could you do the `print("self: \(self)")` and give all the outputs? And do the `didSet` print too? And show only these output, in the order they appear in console?

Comment: @Larme Hey mate, the problem was while trying to present the tabBarController, I wrote a new code now but its getting an error at TableView delegate found nil , ill update the code at both VC's :)

Comment: Your new error is expected, you are using `MonitorimiViewController()`, so creating a new object, but not associated with its xib/Storyboard, so all its IBoutlets are nil, hence the error you are getting.

Comment: @Larme yeh you are correct the new error was on TableView delegate it showed as nil :( , I tried everything but its just not working Larme even seniors couldnt fixed it on remote connection to my macbook :(