# How to assign the stringValue coming from QR code scanner to another variable on another class

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am having problems assigning the stringValue from qrcode scanner to a variable on another class.

1. Scan the QR code
2. the string from QR code need's to be assigned to id variable of the other class
3. perform a segue to that class's viewController

So i created a init on the other class where the variable id is and assigned it to temp as you can see but still the temp is not being assigned to the id variable and when i execute the code it gets error nil to the variable id...?

Class: QRScannerController

```
            if metadataObj.stringValue != nil {
            
            let destVC = MonitorimiViewController(temp: metadataObj.stringValue!)
            destVC.id = metadataObj.stringValue!
            
            do {
                
                guard let tabBarController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBarController") as? UITabBarController else {
                    return
                }
                
                (tabBarController.viewControllers![0] as? MonitorimiViewController)?.id = metadataObj.stringValue!
                tabBarController.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
                tabBarController.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
                self.present(tabBarController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
        captureSession.stopRunning()
    }
```

Class: MonitorimiViewController

```
init(temp : String){
    id = temp
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}


var id:String?


    func fetchAndReloadData(){
    APICaller.shared.getVehicles(for: id!) {[weak self] (result) in     // error nil value at id! 
        guard let self = self else { return }
        
        switch result {
        case .success(let vehicle):
            self.listOfVechicle = vehicle
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.monitorimiTableView.reloadData()
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

For any clarifications please feel free to ask because I have been stuck with this problem for days :(

Comment: make a protocol and pass value via it or could use notification centre.

Comment: I am very new to swift to make that possibly work but ill check it out :) , Thanks Blind Ninja !

Comment: Please do have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70783836/object-stringvalue-from-qr-code-is-not-being-parsed-to-a-variable-in-a-different/70784757#70784757

Comment: @Darshan hey Darshan I am that person who created that post but that account was deactivated for 2 days :( , I cant understand the last part though at the MonitorimiViewController()

Comment: Your code is unclear. You are creating a new `MonitorimiViewController` and set its `id`, but you present the one inside the TabBarController. Could you clarify what's the logic between `QRScannerController` and TabBar and `MonitorimiViewController`? What's the hierarchy exactly?

Comment: @Larme Hey yeh man the logic is the app is about tracking vehicles, I have a tableView on MonitorimiVC that shows the cars, the cars come from API with a unique id, so QR code must scan that stringValue that is the id and parse it to the fetchFunction on the MonitorimiVC so it can show the Vahicles, I hope you understand

Comment: I meant especially the hierarchy?. You are on TabBar, then have a `MonitorimiVC` on it, from it you show `QRScannerController`, and then you want to go back to `MonitorimiVC`, is that right?

Comment: Oh the hierarchy is this:  Fresh user opens the app, the QR code scanner pops up! , then  the user scans the id from a generated QR code and when the users scans it he is redirected to first vc which is [0] Monitorimi , the tabBarController is the one that contains my VC's  Here image how it goes: https://imgur.com/a/h7kE3Dc

Comment: And the QRCode VC is the on on the right of the Monitorimi ?

Comment: @Larme Its the one with the biggest number 1) that is pointing that large arrow to the main tabBarController

Comment: Would you mind adding after `guard let tabBarController...`: `print("Inside QRVC: \(tabBarController.viewControllers![0])`, and `print("Inside QRVC as MonitorimiViewController : \(tabBarController.viewControllers![0] as? MonitorimiViewController))`, you'll see the error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't debug yourself (experience will be earned later), never write this kind of code:

(tabBarController.viewControllers![0] as? MonitorimiViewController)?.id = metadataObj.stringValue!

So, what does it says:

`tabBarController.viewControllers!`: If there is no viewControllers: crash.

`(... as? SomeClass)`: If it's not of that class (or compliant to the protocol, or a subclass, etc.), the cast will fail, and it will be `nil`.

So in your case, it's:

```
(someNilValue)?.id = someId
```

So, nothing gets `someId`.

How to know that by yourself:

```
guard let viewcontrollers = tabBarController.viewControllers else {
    print("tabBarController.viewControllers is nil")
    return
}

guard let firstVC = viewControllers.first else {
    print("viewControllers is empty")
    return
}

guard let asMonitorimiVC = firstVC as? MonitorimiViewController else {
    print("firstVC is NOT a MonitorimiViewController instance: \(firstVC)") //by default, you should see its type in console, by you could also use type(of:)
    return
}

asMonitorimiVC.id = someId
```

Yours should then fail at `guard let asMonitorimiVC`, because `firstVC` is a `UINavigationController`.

```
guard let asNavigationVC = firstVC as? UINavigationController else {
    print("firstVC is NOT a UINavigationController instance: \(firstVC)") //by default, you should see its type in console, by you could also use type(of:)
    return
}

guard let firtVCFromNavVC = asNavigationVC.viewcontrollers.first else {
    print("asNavigationVC.viewcontrollers is empty") //But that shouldn't be the case, I used viewcontrollers, but you could also use topViewController in this case
    return
}

guard let asMonitorimiVC = firtVCFromNavVC as? MonitorimiViewController else {
    print("firtVCFromNavVC is NOT a MonitorimiViewController instance: \(firstVC)") //by default, you should see its type in console, by you could also use type(of:)
    return
}

asMonitorimiVC.id = someId
```

Of course, that's a verbose solution, you might want to cut it a little, but when debugging, do not hesitate to make explicit code:

```
guard let navVC = tabBarController.viewControllers?.first as? UINavigationController else {
print("tabBarController.viewControllers is nil or empty, or the first of it is not a UINavigationController")
return 
}
guard let asMonitorimiVC = navVC.viewControllers.first as? MonitorimiViewController else {
    print("navVC.viewControllers is empty, or its first is not a is NOT a MonitorimiViewController instance: \(navVC.viewControllers.first)")
    return
}
```

Side note: You might notice, that if you had answered correctly [my first question in comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70878583/the-metadataobj-stringvalue-coming-from-the-qr-code-wont-be-assigned-to-a-variab#comment125302242_70878583) in your previous question, we would have spotted directly the issue:

> Is `(tabBarController.viewControllers![0] as? MonitorimiViewController)` `nil`?

Because print("Is it nil: (tabBarController.viewControllers![0] as? MonitorimiViewController))` should show that's it's in fact nil, since the cast fails...

Comment: Hey Larme thanks a lot for your effort man and yes I will learn and am learning, So this is the print: (lldb) print ((tabBarController.viewControllers![0] as? MonitorimiViewController))
((OnTra2.MonitorimiViewController?)) $R3 = {
  some = <uninitialized>

Comment: $R5 = {
  some = <uninitialized>
}

Comment: Sometimes debugger is capricious, what if you have really in your code `print("Is it nil: (tabBarController.viewControllers![0] as? MonitorimiViewController))`?

Comment: As i can see the [0] leads to MonitorimiVC mate

Comment: so that means that its not nil i guess?

Comment: That's strange, it should be a `UINavigationController` according to the screenshot of your Storyboard, not a `MonitorimiViewController`

Comment: It is UINavigationController but its referencing to MonitorimiViewController since its the VC that is assigned to it

Comment: It shouldn't. It should be tabBar - NavVC - MonitorimiVC. In short, `((tabBarController.viewControllers?.first as? UINavigationController)?.viewControllers.first as? MonitorimiViewController).id = someId`

Comment: Yo man it worked man!!! , After 1+ week with this one problem you did it.

Comment: This is a great answer and learning. @ioslifer - please mark this as answer so it can help others and give Larme the credit they deserve.

Comment: @ShawnFrank Yeh it was man , Done he deserves more than a Green mark :)

Comment: Side note: If you had tested the code with the `guard let`, it should have worked, better that the long line in previous comment, that's hard to debug...